# How to reset entity framework data context after error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have a huge codebase using EF and occasionally an error occurs which keeps any additional EF commands from executing.  Our code uses DI so the services should be getting their own instance of the data context.  But it seems like somewhere something is going on where if an error occurs on the context, then any further EF calls will fail and will just throw the original error message.  So it appears that if it fails on an insert, update, or delete, then the next EF call that is made from another place will try to first execute the failing command again and it just continues to error until we stop and restart the application.

So, is there a way in our error handler code that intercepts all exceptions in the application to get any instance of the data context and reset it so that it doesn't continue to error on any later calls to it?